# jTable get data from filtered rows

Tags: java, swing, jtable, row, rowfilter

I want to retrieve some data from a filtered row.
This is how i filter my table :

```
    String makeText = makeFilterCombo.getSelectedItem().toString();
    if (makeText == "All") {
        makeText = "";
    }

    String numar = getEssRegex();

    String impact = impactBox.getSelectedItem().toString();
    if (impact == "All") {
        impact = "";
    }

    TableModel model;
    model = jTable1.getModel();
    final TableRowSorter<TableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<TableModel>(model);
    jTable1.setRowSorter(sorter);

    List<RowFilter<Object, Object>> rfs = new ArrayList<RowFilter<Object, Object>>(2);
    rfs.add(RowFilter.regexFilter(makeText, 2));
    rfs.add(RowFilter.regexFilter(numar, 5));
    rfs.add(RowFilter.regexFilter(impact, 9));

    RowFilter<Object, Object> af = RowFilter.andFilter(rfs);

    sorter.setRowFilter(af);
```

And this is how i try to get a value from a filtered row:

```
    int f = search(connectedCarIndex);

    connectedImage1 = jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(jTable1.convertRowIndexToModel(f), 10).toString();
    connectedImage2 = jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(jTable1.convertRowIndexToModel(f), 11).toString();
    connectedImage3 = jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(jTable1.convertRowIndexToModel(f), 12).toString();

    System.out.println(connectedImage1 + "-------" + connectedImage2 + "------" + connectedImage3);
```

But none of this works ?
Can anybody help me ?
The code works and i can see the connected image name if the rows are shown

Comment: issue must be in rest of your code

Comment: It would help if you indicated what the problem was, exactly. "But none of this works" could mean anything. How did you expect your code to behave? How is it actually behaving? Are there any error messages?

Comment: There are no errors , the code works if the rows are shown . After i click on a row it should print out another row cell value (which is now filtered and not shown)

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Answer (score 3):

```
int f = search(connectedCarIndex);
```

I have no idea what the search(...) method does.

If you are searching the data that is displayed in the table then you would just use:

```
table.getValueAt(...);
```

If you are searching all the data that is stored in the TableModel then you would use:

```
table.getModel().getValueAt(...);
```

there is no need to convert the index if you know what you are searching.